# how to read data from database in a web service using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a web service and I have two textboxes and a button. I want to read data from web service.When I push the button I use a grid view to reach this aim. Is there another way to get data from web service that I can eliminate the gridview?

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    DataSet ds1 = ws.daryafte_view_Personel_Information_with_parameter_cu_personal_number_Taradod(txtCodePers.Text.Trim());
    this.GridView1.DataSource = ds1;

    foreach (System.Data.DataTable tabale1 in ds1.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in tabale1.Rows)
        {
            txtName.Text = dr["tp_firstabbr_name"].ToString().Trim() + "  " + dr["tp_familyoffice_name"].ToString().Trim();
            txtMoavenat.Text = dr["tp_sbu"].ToString().Trim();
            Image1.ImageUrl = "~/image/" + txtCodePers.Text + ".jpg";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are MANY, MANY different ways to "read data from a database" in C#/Asp.Net.  STRONG SUGGESTION: familiarize yourself with [Entity Framework](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/).  It might be "overkill" for this particular app - but it will definitely be useful to know as you developer other, more complex applications.

Comment: @paulsm4: Is there any simplest way for solving this matter? Because I do not have time for learning entity framework